# How to place random characters in grid

Tags: c++

I am working on a assignment and i am stuck. Here is my code of what i have done untill now

```
{
int s = 5;
char player = 'p';
char choice = 0;
int pr = 1,pc = 1;
int dr=2, dc=2;//diamond in row //dimond in column
int br = 3, bc = 3;
int score = 0;
int k = 1;
char d = 'D';
char b = 'B';


while (score != 25){

for (int i = 1; i <= s; i = i + 1){
    k = i;

        for (int j = 1; j <= s; j = j + 1){




            if (i == pr&&j == pc){


                cout << " " << player;
            }
            else if(i==dr&&j==dc){

                cout << " " << d;
            }
            else if (i == br&&j == bc){
                cout << " " << b;
            }
            else if (i == dr + 2 && j==dc + 2){
                cout << " " << d;
            }
            else if (i == br+2&&j == bc-1){
                cout << " " << b;
            }
            else{
                cout << " *";
            }






        }

        cout << endl;



    }


cout << "Enter your choice= ";
cin >> choice;
if (choice == 'd'||choice=='D'){
    pr = pr + 1;

}
if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R'){
    pc = pc + 1;
}
if (choice == 'l' || choice == 'L'){
    pc = pc - 1;
}
if (choice == 'u' || choice == 'U'){
    pr = pr - 1;
}

}
```

}

Now if the player position go on d(diamond) than it should add 1 to score and generate new random position for diamond.That positon should also not overlap with older one. 
I think i have to use `srand` fucntion but how will I use it ?Can anyone guide me Thanks.

Comment: Generate random numbers that correspond to the coordinates of the grid site where the 'B' is to be placed. Then just check in the loop if you hit that site and place the 'B'. Very straight-forward.

Comment: `srand()` just initializes the random number generator. You need to call it once at the beginning of your program. Afterwards, you use `rand()` to actually get some random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually understand what you want to do, but anyway [this is the documentation of srand function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/), with an example.

In a few words, you have to initialize the pseudo-random number generator with a seed (that is recommended to do with `time(NULL)` function because return distinctive runtime value), then just get your pseudo-random number with`rand() % x` where `x` is the upper boundary of the range in which you want to get your number.

If you provide further information, I would be glad to help you.

Enjoy!

**Edit:**

```
char array[5][5];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    array[rand() % 5][rand() % 5] = 'B';
}
```

This will generate two random 'B' in a 5x5 matrix, as you asked.

**Edit 2:**

Before the two nested for loop add:

```
if (pc == dc && pr == dr) {
    score++;
    int newDc = rand() % 5;
    int newDr = rand() % 5;
    // keep generating random numbers until you find one that is different
    // from the previous one.
    while (newDc == dc) newDc = rand % 5;
    while (newDr == dr) newDr = rand % 5;
    // when you find it, change it
    dc = newDc;
    dr = newDr;
}
```

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: It's not *official* though.

Comment: I wanted to generate random positon for bomb in game. First i need to add two bombs randomly in grid 5x5 and i dont know how to do it.Than if i move my player to bomb than it will add 1 to my score and generate new poistion for that bomb.

Comment: @Francesco Alongi Thanks man but i am anot allowed to use array.Please can you check program edit up.

Comment: diamond disappear after 2nd generation.